# How should I build a chat client that works in multiple instances of a server?

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, socket.io, chat

so I'm building a chat client in nodejs and trying to figure this out. I'm using heroku to deploy my server, which means there will be multiple instances of my server running. To solve the problem of a user connecting to a server where its socket is not initialized, I'm using sticky sessions. Now my problem is, when one of my instances gets a message, how should I send it to another user that may be initialized on another instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to use some shared resource like a Redis database or some pub/sub service like Faye or Kafka, or a queue service like ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ. This is what is usually done to make things like that work across multiple instances of the server. You could also use a CouchDB changes feed, or a similar feature of RethinkDB to make sure that all of your instances get all the data as soon as it is posted by any one of them.

See:

- http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/changes.html
- https://rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/javascript/
- https://redis.io/topics/pubsub
- https://faye.jcoglan.com/
- https://kafka.apache.org/